# How to deal with Xcode Missing File warning in a Git repository?

Tags: swift, xcode, git, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm using GIT for the source control in my Xcode project. After updating a cocoapod library, I started getting warnings like the following:

file:///Users/NinjaDev/Development/Xcode/NinjaApp/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Download.swift: warning: Missing file: /Users/NinjaDev/Development/Xcode/NinjaApp/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Download.swift is missing from working copy

The library changed, so that Download.swift file is no longer there. I committed the project and did a clean and rebuild, but am still getting the error. I'm guessing the repository doesn't know it was deleted, but I'm not very familiar with the internal workings of Git...what's the correct way to fix this and prevent it from happening again?

Edit: Per Aspirin2D's suggestion, here is the git status. The git log didn't have anything unusual.

**Git Status**

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Podfile.lock
    deleted:    Pods/Alamofire/Source/Download.swift
    deleted:    Pods/Alamofire/Source/Manager.swift
    deleted:    Pods/Alamofire/Source/Stream.swift
    deleted:    Pods/Alamofire/Source/Upload.swift
    modified:   Pods/Manifest.lock
    deleted:    Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/RAMAnimatedTabBarController.xcscheme
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/LICENSE
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/Animations/BounceAnimation/RAMBounceAnimation.swift
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/Animations/FrameAnimation/RAMFrameItemAnimation.swift
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/Animations/FumeAnimation/RAMFumeAnimation.swift
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/Animations/RotationAnimation/RAMRotationAnimation.swift
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/Animations/TransitionAniamtions/RAMTransitionItemAnimations.swift
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController.swift
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMBadge/RAMBadge.swift
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMItemAnimationProtocol.swift
    deleted:    Pods/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/README.md
    deleted:    Pods/Target Support Files/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/Info.plist
    deleted:    Pods/Target Support Files/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController-dummy.m
    deleted:    Pods/Target Support Files/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController-prefix.pch
    deleted:    Pods/Target Support Files/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController-umbrella.h
    deleted:    Pods/Target Support Files/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController.modulemap
    deleted:    Pods/Target Support Files/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController.xcconfig
    modified:   NinjaApp.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/NinjaDev.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Pods/Alamofire/Source/SessionDelegate.swift
    Pods/Alamofire/Source/SessionManager.swift
    Pods/Alamofire/Source/TaskDelegate.swift
    Pods/Local Podspecs/UIColor_Hex_Swift.podspec.json
    NinjaApp.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/NinjaDev.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/NinjaData.xcscheme
    NinjaApp.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/NinjaDev.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/NinjaWebservices.xcscheme

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

EDIT 2: I figured out what happened. When I committed in Xcode, the files I removed must have been unchecked by default. While messing with the problem, I brought up the commit menu again, and sure enough it was just a bunch of unchecked files. Check them and committing again fixed the warnings. **Why does Xcode leave some files unchecked by default?**

Comment: i don't think the problem by xcode because i don't see file project.pbxproj changed

Answer (score 2):

the warning, maybe it's not caused by git... 
Open terminal,;CD to the project's folder;type 'git status' and 'git log', to find out what happened to the source file. And check the project settings in the Xcode again. Tell me more details about that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The git status shows that some files are not committed...but I did a commit/push through Xcode. Maybe a bug, or maybe I'm not understanding something correctly?

Comment: I found a solution, please see edits and leave a comment.

Comment: In my opinion, ALWAYS using git with command lines, it's clear and pridictable

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using source tree. After upgrading to swift 3, many files from different frameworks were changed, and I got warning about them being missing. In source tree, moving the files changed from unstaged to staged resulted in the warnings disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who get here from a search engine:

When this happened to me  (Xcode 8.2.1; swift 3), I also noticed that several files were unchecked. I believe what happened is a file was staged in git but renamed before the commit.

To fix it, just open terminal and type

```
git reset HEAD path/to/file.swift
```

A note of this is made in the output of `git status` as well.